# got error Unable to find source file to my Windows-CE project

Tags: windows-ce, setup-project, cab

i try to build cab from my windows-CE project

and i got this error:

> Error 5 Unable to find source file 'D:\MySetup_Setup\System.Data.SqlServerCe.DLL' for assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.DLL', located in '%CE1%\MySetup'   D:\MySetup_Setup.vddproj

all the dll are in place and the project works excellent

what can be the problem ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We'd have to see the source INF file that CABWIZ is using generate the CAB.  My guess is that `system.data.sqlserverce.dll` is not in the `d:\mysetup_setup` folder on the development machine.